# Getting started with line-rate virtual machine

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, sdn

I am beginning to study the use of virtual machines with realtime applications, specifically network applications.
While I do understand the limitations and concerns, I'd like to get ideas as to how to get started on this task.
I am going to use a DPDK sample application over Linux, and probably use VMWare for starters. However, I do not know what my first steps with respect to setting up VMWare should be.

Answer (score 0):

First I think it is better to use open source solution like QUEM/KVM for your virtualization platform. Many platform exist for run high performance network functions on virtualized platforms you can see [OpenNetVM](http://sdnfv.github.io/onvm/) for example in order to get basic ideas.